# Unable to get data from Scrapy API

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm facing some unexpected issues while trying to get data from an API request. I found that it is throwing a "500" error and also this error message. I'm trying to scrape this URL "https://www.machinerytrader.com/listings/for-sale/excavators/1031" but I have no idea what I actually missing here.

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 2)
```

This is what I tried so far,

```
import scrapy
import json


class ListingSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'listing'
    allowed_domains = ['www.machinerytrader.com']
    # start_urls = ['https://www.machinerytrader.com/listings/for-sale/excavators/1031']

    def start_requests(self):
        payload = {
            "Category":"1031",
            "sort": "1",
            "page":"2"
            }
        headers= {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
            "authority": "www.machinerytrader.com",
            "method": "GET",
            "path": "/ajax/listings/ajaxsearch?Category=1031&sort=1&page=2",
            "scheme": "https",
            "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "cookie": "ASP.NET_SessionId=uircx3p1up0gs3we43zfy3xp; Tracking=SessionStarted=1&UserReferrer=&GUID=75541984850425423381; __RequestVerificationToken=CqqhcuoUxcCh_VvGb2QkZPTMG1sygAxcDjWmGutWxYGvIScO7I1rCwBZabShMlyTl9syCA2; BIGipServerwww.machinery_tradesites_http_pool=545368256.20480.0000; ln_or=eyI0MjU0ODkyIjoiZCJ9; AMP_TOKEN=%24NOT_FOUND; _gid=GA1.2.104780578.1678372555; _fbp=fb.1.1678372557791.1218325782; _hjFirstSeen=1; _hjIncludedInSessionSample_1143836=1; _hjSession_1143836=eyJpZCI6IjU1ZGYyOGJmLWQ4YjktNGU2Mi04NjU2LWUwYmJkYzdiNGMxMSIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NzgzNzI1NTgzNDcsImluU2FtcGxlIjp0cnVlfQ==; _hjIncludedInPageviewSample=1; _hjAbsoluteSessionInProgress=1; __gads=ID=2a38a4e969861bb1:T=1678372561:S=ALNI_MarB5bgIDdhzpQPECKDmX-70INeJg; __gpi=UID=00000bd5f25a7b4b:T=1678372561:RT=1678372561:S=ALNI_MapbcTx6haLt65wewjezZyeMFVtCw; _hjSessionUser_1143836=eyJpZCI6IjI3ODM2ZDdhLTc0YzUtNTIwMi05YjdhLWYxMmM5YTk4ZGNmNiIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOjE2NzgzNzI1NTgzMzksImV4aXN0aW5nIjp0cnVlfQ==; __atuvc=2%7C10; __atuvs=6409eecd9390ad6d001; Top_PopUp=true; reese84=3:MhdsyFtuLMcDbPfjHYfnUQ==:Xnyj2+4WPTbNOTnv4Aj99+6mLrSjYnrQVoSGqCJEwqmN/gdPfQuCPFYN1/1sInEQHaUvLNdN2VbgdxeC96k6tr1MUSbHd2GxI4AKb1CxnkZfLm63/CXWNqJ/vlS66hOTSsEn+gxPb2l3g2TD3RGi0H4PjyhskjDIE10USkPi3mm83aG/xkAYL4khuWtRDaYzyHjzQ76f9yRr0tNnEEbUPbxZTW7BPXcEF606e6mzq6v5/YEy17JScccw/CCkXb4Uv1tzeNYhkMuFj5V5upY0a2tC/MiJeCACNCYnX9obZhGsfPbL6VUYdJDEhmyR8OBJsHuH4BwOdjnbr7pFG+o4AZKqDHliWKhUnDxGAHIhKwzhhq5TFjeJbqRwSLrMXH54WxZZHcuvRtwr734U2F3Pmf8NqW+zavYdB/aYrk+HpA9LfQQQFBGd/1FNRAM0e8fxZpj5U/DxTKPMdvwK5qBnfzQaTzycDwe80G7QRYX9kf4=:gQlue37nFKz2zVkiSWGW9vURldmXHHEIxHz2yiUrtF8=; _uetsid=b29154b0be8711edabac07f5e20bba65; _uetvid=b2917380be8711edbb2587449262974a; _ga=GA1.2.1777003444.1678372555; UserID=ID=n2K08gLg7XRct%2fxxJeWEnGDwbYpUh6vQ%2fiE1eBN%2f25lkMV4lKXFpeoTT54DrUsz9CriJRnchYL4PfEPzqxaCRA%3d%3d&LV=sHEWMHROf%2fDobQFZDWX1nWtv%2bf2Uk9i6YA9N5Sk0lGE%2fWiDudiekp7MPDIUnH0jGKMx9VZbhLzD4VuT7pKbqepCdPLaN274I; UserSettingsCookie=screenSize=1246|947; _ga_27QWK2FVDW=GS1.1.1678372557.1.1.1678373273.60.0.0",
            "pragma": "no-cache",
            "referer": "https://www.machinerytrader.com/listings/for-sale/excavators/1031",
            "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
            "sec-ch-ua-platform": "Windows",
            "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
            "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
            "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
            "x-xsrf-token": "lKwor8adm67mnDJjariTC1-_x2sWvmjxDtVZerZ6p03OwqvVc10YVZUQMmD4-pTv7E2cTSN-8rsTW6ISckmZVgBek66eHw3iFUngI3jYt6h_rwqQ3pI_QxPjYH1us7eHyW27lxFL_-wSS3QC0",
            "sec-ch-ua": '"Google Chrome";v="111", "Not(A:Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="111"',
            }

        yield scrapy.Request(
                url="https://www.machinerytrader.com/ajax/listings/ajaxsearch?Category=1031&sort=1&page=2",
                method="GET",
                headers=headers,
                body=json.dumps(payload),
                callback=self.parse
                )

    def parse(self, response):
        json_resp = json.loads(response.body)
        products = json_resp['Listings']
        
        yield {
            'DealerLocation': products['DealerLocation'],
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a xsrf-token to make these requests, in this case you can make a request to the home page first (https://www.machinerytrader.com/), and then grab the token using a selector (`//input[@name="__XSRF-TOKEN"]/@value`). Add this value to the next request headers and the request will work. It would look like this:

```
import scrapy
import json


class ListingSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "listing"
    allowed_domains = ["www.machinerytrader.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.machinerytrader.com/listings/for-sale/excavators/1031"]

    def start_requests(self):
        # You don't need that many headers
        headers = {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
        }

        yield scrapy.Request(
            url="https://www.machinerytrader.com/",
            headers=headers,
            method="GET",
            callback=self.parse,
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        xsrf_token = response.xpath('//input[@name="__XSRF-TOKEN"]/@value').get()

        headers = {
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
            "x-xsrf-token": xsrf_token,
        }

        yield scrapy.Request(
            url="https://www.machinerytrader.com/ajax/listings/ajaxsearch?Category=1031&sort=1&page=2",
            method="GET",
            headers=headers,
            callback=self.parse_response,
        )

    def parse_response(self, response):
        json_resp = json.loads(response.body)
        products = json_resp['Listings']
        yield {
            'DealerLocation': products['DealerLocation'],
            }
```

If you want to run/schedule this or many spiders you can consider using [estela](https://github.com/bitmakerla/estela) which is a spider management solution.

Comment: This error is showing now  'DealerLocation': products['DealerLocation'],
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: So, I have added a for loop and it is working fine.

for product in products:
            yield {
                'DealerLocation': product['DealerLocation'],
                }

Comment: Nice, I didn't modify that part of the code (the sample code you sent)